# Classic ASP VBScript object to array

Tags: web-services, vbscript, asp-classic

I don't normally deal with VBScript and classic ASP but I have to make some changes to one of our old sites.

I use a SOAP Web Service to get an array of string values, but when I try to consume it from within the classic ASP code it tells me it's an object

The service works, it returns an array of strings, the code is sound, I just need to know how to change it from an object to string I think.

The web service WSDL:

```xml
<xs:element name="getProductFunctionsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Error

> Object not a collection

Classic ASP code:

```
result2 = soap.getProductFunctions("AEDO")
i = 0
For Each present In result2
    If mid(user_auth_key,i,1) = 1 Then
        response.write("success")
    End If
    response.write(present)
    response.write("<br />")
    i = i+1
Next
```

Comment: VBScript is scripting language, as such it's not possible to perform type casting so the problem might be more severe than you think. First, let's debug this: when you have `Response.Write(result2)` what you get? What about `Response.Write(CStr(result2))`? And finally `Response.Write(TypeName(result2))`? Please let us know the output of each and it might shed some light on the problem.

Comment: +1 Shadow Wizard. I guess the type name is `String()` and VBScript cannot handle it. (if I'm not wrong) **@David** You could add one more optional parameter for backward compatibility to your web service. If it's `classic-asp`, your web service returns a delimited string instead of `array of string`. And you could split returned value in classic asp, so it's iterable.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your responses, I will be looking at this in about an hour and will report my progress.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the word SET, since this is returning an object?

```
SET result2 = soap.getProductFunctions("AEDO")
```